# Privacy policy & Web Server Log data on Shared hosting?

Tags: web-hosting, webserver, shared-hosting, privacy-policy

I am very confused with how shared hosting works?

I asked my web hosting provider that, "How can I delete all my website's web server log files/data which gets automatically generated by APACHE server?" My hosting provider answered me, since you have shared hosting, you do not have access to server level, so you cannot delete those files.

Now, Question arises, if I do not have control over those data, then what I should write in my website's privacy policy regarding the WEB SERVER LOG files?

Very thanks in advance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add **a "Log Data" clause** in your Privacy Policy to inform users that your web server will collect this data automatically.

An example of this kind of clause:

[image: Log Data clause via TermsFeed]

There are certain examples of Privacy Policies where the website [does not collect personal data](https://termsfeed.com/blog/privacy-policy-no-personal-data-collected/), but these examples are very limited as most websites will collect at least some pieces of data (for example, automated web servers logs) even if the data isn't used by the business.

Comment: That was my confusion. Thx for solution. Along with that could you let us know, whether as a site owner we are obliged to delete those log files after some time, or just informing user about what we collect are just file? If we want also we cannot on shared hosting as they are controlled by hosting provider.